# MYSQL multiple counts on table with joins

Tags: mysql, count

Ok so i have this SQL query

```
$query = "
            SELECT
                c.category, count(t.id_ticket) as ticket_count, count(tm.id_message) as message_count
            FROM
                tickets t
            LEFT JOIN
                ticketMessages tm
            ON
                t.id_ticket = tm.id_ticket
            LEFT JOIN
                categories c
            ON
                t.id_category = c.id_category
            GROUP BY
                t.id_category
        ";
```

So basically i have a ticket table, each ticket can have multiple messages and each ticket has one category its assigned to.

Now lets assume the following

I have 2 tickets in the red category and there are 5 messages in total
I have 4 tickets in the blue category and there are 10 messages in total
I have 3 tickets in the black category and there are 7 messages in total

What i want to do is show something like this:

```
[0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["category"]=>
    string(12) "Red"
    ["id_ticket_count"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["id_message_count"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
[1]=>
array(4) {
  ["category"]=>
  string(12) "Blue"
  ["id_ticket_count"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["id_message_count"]=>
  string(2) "10"
}
[1]=>
array(4) {
  ["category"]=>
  string(12) "Black"
  ["id_ticket_count"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["id_message_count"]=>
  string(2) "7"
}
```

However my SQL returns the same value for both messages and tickets, that value is messages but i also want to know how many tickets. I assumed counting id_ticket.

If i add group by t.ticket_id then it shows a new array item for every ticket, so i end up with 2 red category items, 4 blue and 3 black items but it should only show 1 item per category with the counts for each category.

If it helps the tables would look something like this

```
Category
id_category | category
1 | red
2 | blue
3 | black

Tickets
id_ticket | id_category 
1 | 1
2 | 1
3 | 2
4 | 2
5 | 2
6 | 2
7 | 3
8 | 3
9 | 3

Messages
id_message | id_ticket
1 | 1
2 | 1
3 | 2
4 | 2
5 | 2
6 | 3
7 | 3
8 | 3
9 | 4
10 | 4
11 | 4
12 | 5
13 | 5
14 | 5
15 | 6
16 | 7
17 | 7
18 | 8
19 | 8
20 | 9
21 | 9
22 | 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to use a `CASE WHEN` clause to handle cardinality issues more properly. As far I know using **count** can lead to **NULL** values due those tickets those have no messages assigned to, be counted as 1 misleading valid row.

Maybe something like

```
           SELECT
            c.category, count(t.id_ticket) as ticket_count,
            SUM(CASE WHEN tm.id_message IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as message_count
        FROM
            tickets t
        LEFT JOIN
            ticketMessages tm
        ON
            t.id_ticket = tm.id_ticket
        LEFT JOIN
            categories c
        ON
            t.id_category = c.id_category
        GROUP BY
            t.id_category
```

I'm assuming there's a **1:many** relationship between **tickets** and **ticketMessages**.

Answer (score 0):

This SHOULD get you what you are looking for.  You want DISTINCT tickets at the same time you are getting the TOTAL count of messages

```
SELECT
      c.category,
      COUNT( distinct t.id_ticket ) as UniqueTickets,
      COUNT(tm.id_ticket) TotalMsgsPerTickets
   from
      Categories c
         LEFT JOIN tickets t
            ON c.id_category = t.id_Category
            left join ticketMessages tm
               ON t.id_ticket = tm.id_ticket
   group by
      c.id_Category
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery for lowest level table to achieve this:

```
SELECT  c.category, 
    count(t.id_ticket) as ticket_count,
    SUM((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ticketMessages WHERE id_ticket =  t.id_ticket)) as message_count
    FROM tickets t
    INNER JOIN categories c ON t.id_category = c.id_category
    GROUP BY t.id_category
```

Answer (score 0):

> So basically i have a ticket table each ticket can have multiple messages

I am assuming that each ticket can have messages, and can have no messages at all.

> and each ticket has one category its assigned to.

And that all tickets should have their own corresponding category.

Following the result that you want, you can use this query:

```
SELECT C.category
  , COUNT(DISTINCT T.id_ticket) AS id_ticket_count
  , COUNT(M.id_ticket) AS id_message_count
  FROM Category C
  INNER JOIN Tickets T ON T.id_category = C.id_category
  LEFT JOIN Messages M ON M.id_ticket = T.id_ticket
  GROUP BY C.id_category
```

Please check the result in [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f748f/3/0).

Answer (score 0):

`Count` will return the total number of rows returned for each group specified in the `group by`.

`Count(Distinct "fieldName")` will return the distinct value count for the field specified.
In your case: `count(t.id_ticket)`, `count(tm.id_message)` or even `count(*)` would return the same value (the number of rows for each group).

From the give SQL statement you should also be careful with the `GROUP BY` clause, since MySql will allow you to use strange group combinations! In general have in mind that whatever columns you have in the `Select` clause and are not aggregated should be included in the `group by` clause.